# Apache access log for IP address

Tags: apache, logging, ip

How do I output the entire access log for a specific IP address only (from `access.log`)?

In other words, an access log that only contains details from a specific IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with unix command line tools then you can also try grep or awk. Here's how you can use grep. Replace the IP with the one you are looking for and access.log with the full path to that file on your system.

```
grep 123.345.678.129 access.log
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file and paste it on desktop or any other directory.
no open new excel file.
In excel, Go to Data From file, select all files type, open the file and import.

Select fixed width in original data type and finish.

select the first column and click on data ->filter

now select you can select data with  ip now.